# Как открыть файлы FileZilla в VisualStudioCode

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, filezilla, ubuntu-software

Я прописываю на FileZilla свои данные и там выходить мои файлы например index.html и когда я хочу его открыть там предлагают выбрать программу по умолчанию там когда выбираю его то там на простом блокноте открывает а когда нажимаю на **Выбрать программу** то не получается найти путь Visual Stuido Code его я установил с Ubuntu Software.

Вопрос заключается в том что как мне открывать файлы на редакторе vscode а не на блокноте.

Comment: @donRumata не выражаться)

Comment: Перечитал ещё 2 раза. Файл `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop` есть? И какое у него содержимое?